# How do I move an HTML div with PHP content using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have created a web-based e-learning module. Users will use a web browser to view and navigate through the module. I have two buttons labeled as 'back' and 'next' for users to get through the module. All content on each page is controlled by PHP arrays to place the text that the user sees on the page. My HTML/PHP code is:

```
<div id="white">

        <div id="header">
            <img id="header_logo"  src="./images/tfx_logo3.png" /img>
            <div id="mod-title">
                <div id="tab-shape"></div>
                <h1><?php echo $module; ?></h1>
            </div>
            <div id="nav-bar">
                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li><a href="./main_menu.php">Myths</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>


        <h2><?php echo $heading[$page-1]; ?></h2>

        <div class ="ref">

            <?php echo $ref[$page-1];?>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-btns">
            <?php

                if ($page != 1) {
                    echo '<a id="prev" href="' . $filename . '.php?page=' . ($page-1) . '">Back</a>';
                }

                if (!in_array($page+1, $progress_pages) && $page != $last_page) {           
                    echo '<a id="next" href="' . $filename . '.php?page=' . ($page+1) . '">Next</a>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<a id="next" href="progress_check.php?page=' . ($page+1) . '">Next</a>';
                }


                ?>

        </div>
```

My problem is that the navigation buttons 'back' and next appear on top of the content see below:

[image]

How do I fix this? is it a CSS problem? The CSS is

```
.ref{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border:  1px, solid #ccc;
    padding: 0px 7px;

}

.nav-btns {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:600px;
}
```

Comment: To view the image click link  where it says "see below"

Comment: We need to see your CSS as well to help you.

Comment: As Russ J commented we need to see your CSS + where you want buttons to be?

Comment: thanks Russ J.  Can you please tell me how to add the CSS to this post.  I tried to post it as a comment but its too long.  Im new to this ..

Comment: Edit your question and post it as a code block in your question content.

Comment: You should only post relevant parts of the code / css. See [mcve]

Comment: thank you DarkBee.  I think the problem is with this CSS: 
.ref{
 width: 50%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 border:  1px, solid #ccc;
 padding: 0px 7px;
 
}

.nav-btns {
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top:600px;
}

Comment: Thanks Ingus.  I want the buttons to appear at the bottom of the page in the center.

Comment: Using CSS absolute you have specifically placed the nav buttons at that location.

Comment: Looks like part of your problem is position: absolute. I would suggest reviewing about the CSS position property https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Thank you Andy G, so your saying that 'absolute' is the reason the buttons show in that location..but why? because each page will be different I thought using absolute would place the buttons in the same position underneath the content on every page.  how do I fix the problem?

Comment: @ Russ J , no. Absolute positinoned elements are positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor. Not to the entire page. In this case they ' seem ' to be positioned relative to the entire page but i guess they are positioned relative to the `white` div element.

Comment: @BullockFoundation please read up on [this link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-understand-css-position-absolute-once-and-for-all-b71ca10cd3fd) and [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for some very good guidance on (absolute) Positioning in CSS. Cheers

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you want to achieve? you want the buttons to be at the bottom ( right after the text, regardless how much text there is ) or you want it to be at a specific position from the top, or you want it to be at the bottom of the page even if the text is just for eg two lines.

Comment: Martin thank you for the reference info.

Comment: Hello Mihai T and thank you.  Yes I want the buttons at the bottom regardless of how much text there is.

Comment: at the bottom of the page ( visible page ) or at the bottom of the text ? :)

Comment: at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
.nav-btns {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:600px;
}
```

to

```
.nav-btns {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Let me know the result!

Comment: Thanks Ingus, I tried it but it didn't work.  I notice that all other pages have the buttons in the correct location accept for this page though.

Answer (score 0):

To add it at the bottom of the page ( just like a 'sticky-footer' ) you can use flexbox. See example below.

```css
.nav-btns {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-btns a {
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:20px;
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
  padding: 5px 40px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#white {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.ref {
   flex: 1;
}
body { 
  margin:0 
}
```

```html
<div id="white">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Header here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="ref">

    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium 
   
     

  </div>
  <div class="nav-btns">
    <a href="#">Back</a>
    <a href="#">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks mihai T,but for some reason it is not working for me.

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand correctly what you wanted. Does the result of my answer look like what you want to achieve?

Comment: Mihai T, Yes it looks like what i need.  Its just not working on my end.

Comment: @BullockFoundation can you replicate what happens on your end ? or at least another image ?

Comment: its doing the same thing which is nothing. it looks exactly like what I posted except for it has a red background now.  your code works as I did it on codepen.  im wondering if my server is the reason i cant see any change

Comment: do the other styles get applied ? on `white` and `ref` ? can you see them when you inspect the element ?

Comment: the styles do get applied and I can see them.  It was my server.  But the buttons still are not center

Comment: @BullockFoundation centered horizontally ? well thats a different question. Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that you are using `absolute` position. Instead you should use `fixed` position. This would solve your issue. And you would need to add `padding-bottom` to your content `div` so the content doesn't get cut behind navigation.

Additionally, I would suggest to use `class` instead of `id` unless you are using them in javascript. I have created a quick basic structure if you would like to use.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: #666;
}

.content {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    /* Padding bottom should be same as footer height.
     * Increase this value if there is increase in navigation height
     */
    padding-bottom: 36px;
}

.nav {
    background-color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav a {
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #00c8ff;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="header"></div>

        <div class="content">
            <h2>Myth#1</h2>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi asperiores, culpa earum illo inventore, laudantium maxime non numquam omnis quo quod tempore, veritatis vitae voluptas.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam aspernatur atque blanditiis corporis illum, soluta unde. At deleniti doloribus minima optio! Aspernatur atque illo ipsam ipsum labore modi omnis provident quasi. Adipisci assumenda aut eius enim expedita facilis labore magnam nihil porro, quod rem repudiandae tenetur? Delectus doloremque ex modi perferendis possimus! Cumque eaque harum obcaecati quaerat. A ab consequatur dolorum error est eveniet fugit harum, hic ipsam ipsum laboriosam libero magnam mollitia nemo nulla obcaecati repellendus sapiente similique unde voluptate! Amet, deleniti illum libero nemo repudiandae sapiente tenetur veritatis. Ad blanditiis, commodi corporis, delectus doloremque expedita facere illo iusto natus necessitatibus nesciunt nobis obcaecati odio qui sequi sint vel. Accusamus ad adipisci asperiores atque autem cum dolor dolore dolores doloribus dolorum ducimus esse eum fuga fugit illo ipsa ipsam iste laborum magni, minima numquam obcaecati odio perferendis perspiciatis placeat quae quam qui quidem ratione rem reprehenderit repudiandae, sequi suscipit.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur atque culpa delectus doloribus ducimus et, facere labore laborum maxime nam nesciunt quaerat quas quidem suscipit tempora veritatis voluptatibus! Ipsa nobis similique vero voluptatem? Ab accusamus alias aliquid animi consectetur corporis delectus dolorem eaque eligendi error esse et expedita facere, hic id illo illum in ipsum labore maiores molestiae nam odit placeat porro provident quaerat qui quisquam ratione reiciendis sint sunt totam vel voluptas? Accusantium adipisci, consequuntur fugit illo itaque sapiente temporibus? Architecto, cupiditate eius, esse et ex illum inventore labore magnam maiores omnis quae, quod quos rem repellat similique voluptatum!</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi asperiores, culpa earum illo inventore, laudantium maxime non numquam omnis quo quod tempore, veritatis vitae voluptas.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam aspernatur atque blanditiis corporis illum, soluta unde. At deleniti doloribus minima optio! Aspernatur atque illo ipsam ipsum labore modi omnis provident quasi. Adipisci assumenda aut eius enim expedita facilis labore magnam nihil porro, quod rem repudiandae tenetur? Delectus doloremque ex modi perferendis possimus! Cumque eaque harum obcaecati quaerat. A ab consequatur dolorum error est eveniet fugit harum, hic ipsam ipsum laboriosam libero magnam mollitia nemo nulla obcaecati repellendus sapiente similique unde voluptate! Amet, deleniti illum libero nemo repudiandae sapiente tenetur veritatis. Ad blanditiis, commodi corporis, delectus doloremque expedita facere illo iusto natus necessitatibus nesciunt nobis obcaecati odio qui sequi sint vel. Accusamus ad adipisci asperiores atque autem cum dolor dolore dolores doloribus dolorum ducimus esse eum fuga fugit illo ipsa ipsam iste laborum magni, minima numquam obcaecati odio perferendis perspiciatis placeat quae quam qui quidem ratione rem reprehenderit repudiandae, sequi suscipit.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur atque culpa delectus doloribus ducimus et, facere labore laborum maxime nam nesciunt quaerat quas quidem suscipit tempora veritatis voluptatibus! Ipsa nobis similique vero voluptatem? Ab accusamus alias aliquid animi consectetur corporis delectus dolorem eaque eligendi error esse et expedita facere, hic id illo illum in ipsum labore maiores molestiae nam odit placeat porro provident quaerat qui quisquam ratione reiciendis sint sunt totam vel voluptas? Accusantium adipisci, consequuntur fugit illo itaque sapiente temporibus? Architecto, cupiditate eius, esse et ex illum inventore labore magnam maiores omnis quae, quod quos rem repellat similique voluptatum!</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi asperiores, culpa earum illo inventore, laudantium maxime non numquam omnis quo quod tempore, veritatis vitae voluptas.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam aspernatur atque blanditiis corporis illum, soluta unde. At deleniti doloribus minima optio! Aspernatur atque illo ipsam ipsum labore modi omnis provident quasi. Adipisci assumenda aut eius enim expedita facilis labore magnam nihil porro, quod rem repudiandae tenetur? Delectus doloremque ex modi perferendis possimus! Cumque eaque harum obcaecati quaerat. A ab consequatur dolorum error est eveniet fugit harum, hic ipsam ipsum laboriosam libero magnam mollitia nemo nulla obcaecati repellendus sapiente similique unde voluptate! Amet, deleniti illum libero nemo repudiandae sapiente tenetur veritatis. Ad blanditiis, commodi corporis, delectus doloremque expedita facere illo iusto natus necessitatibus nesciunt nobis obcaecati odio qui sequi sint vel. Accusamus ad adipisci asperiores atque autem cum dolor dolore dolores doloribus dolorum ducimus esse eum fuga fugit illo ipsa ipsam iste laborum magni, minima numquam obcaecati odio perferendis perspiciatis placeat quae quam qui quidem ratione rem reprehenderit repudiandae, sequi suscipit.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur atque culpa delectus doloribus ducimus et, facere labore laborum maxime nam nesciunt quaerat quas quidem suscipit tempora veritatis voluptatibus! Ipsa nobis similique vero voluptatem? Ab accusamus alias aliquid animi consectetur corporis delectus dolorem eaque eligendi error esse et expedita facere, hic id illo illum in ipsum labore maiores molestiae nam odit placeat porro provident quaerat qui quisquam ratione reiciendis sint sunt totam vel voluptas? Accusantium adipisci, consequuntur fugit illo itaque sapiente temporibus? Architecto, cupiditate eius, esse et ex illum inventore labore magnam maiores omnis quae, quod quos rem repellat similique voluptatum!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="nav">
            <a href="#" class="nav-prev">Prev</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-next">Next</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```